# Prevent loading of slideshow's images in responsive web design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slideshow

I have a slideshow jquery plugin in our website. I am working on making responsive my website. I don't want to show the slideshow on mobile resolutions. However it can be hidden using `display:none`, but it causes extra useless information downloads on mobile devices.

Is there anyway to prevent loading slideshow images on mobiles?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using [**media query**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and include background image

for example if you include image

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 
  // css here only applied when min-width: 768px  and  max-width: 979px    

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a JavaScript?

Include jQuery slideshow plugin, as usual, but prevent it (anyway) from auto-starting. Then write a simple `if`, that will check `window` object to see current viewport (user) dimensions. And if they fall into lets call it "*a mobile range*" (just like in media queries) then simply don't start the slideshow.

If slideshow plugin is written correctly, it should support manual, no-auto start of slideshow and it should not request any images (thus limiting bandwith) until slideshow actually starts. If yours doesn't support these, consider changing plugin. There are hundreds, if not thousands, plugins like that around.