# Don't want slideshow to load assets for small window sizes/mobile

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design

Similar to this question [Prevent loading of slideshow's images in responsive web design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725187/prevent-loading-of-slideshows-images-in-responsive-web-design)

I want to use some sort of jquery slider that is not just responsive, but also allows a setting to disable the downloading of images at certain screen sizes. I keep searching around and there are a lot of responsive jquery sliders, but can't find any that speak of NOT downloading images when the screen is at a minimum size.

I do understand that a responsive slider by nature will scale to whatever (and I have seen some that allow you to declare a max width)... but I wish I could find a responsive slider that allowed for disabling the slideshow (or just not downloading the images, and I can make the #container disappear using css { display: none; }) if the images are NOT being loaded.

Can anyone steer me to such a slider, or show me the code to adjust for one?

This one seemed to be one of my top options so far: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Could you check window size, then only if it's large enough, insert the slider elements into a parent with JS?

Comment: If it is that easy I guess I'm surprised I can't find anything from someone who has done it. I just don't have those skills (javascript) to do it myself. Plus, it would be a bonus if even jquery did not load based on windows size too. The most important thing is not loading the images though (~100kb-200kb each).

Comment: How do you plan to store the image paths?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/trojansdestroy/SZKmc/) is a solution that uses jQuery to determine the window height & width, and only fills the slideContainer div if they meet the minimum dimensions.

```
var contents = '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides"><li><img width="160" height="160" src="http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Plain-Black-Wallpaper.png" /></li><li><img width="160" height="160" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/red/red-06.jpg" /></li><li><img width="160" height="160" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_5xJ_jlTUVG4/S_PHdyb_jyI/AAAAAAAABEg/FKj-Z8K-4WM/s320/bigstockphoto_Blue_Brushed_4167376.jpg" /></li></ul></div>';

$(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 600 &&
    $(window).height() > 200) {
    alert("Window wider than 600px and taller than 200px. Loading images and slider!");
    $("#slideContainer").html(contents);
}
else alert("No slider for you.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just images, then you could use this snippet I've created for my site:

```
setTimeout(function() { loadImages(); }, 1000);
    function loadImages() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
            $('.load-image').each(function(i,obj) {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('loaded-image')) {
                    var src = $(this).data('src');
                    $(this).attr('src',src).fadeTo(1000,1).removeClass('load-image').addClass('loaded-image');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It runs of jQuery, so its not a solution if you're not using it already and don't want to use it at all. Basically it works by using a spacer image that is very small (~1kb for example) that is replaced out using jQuery.

Syntax: `<img src="library/pictures/spacer.gif" data-src="fullsize-image" class="load-image">`

You can see it in action [here](http://robsterlini.co.uk).

The one caviat though is that it won't load if the user has javascript turned on, but you could  alternates if that's necessary.

Alternatively, if you're just using CSS background-images, use media-queries to eliminate the backgrounds for smaller sizes so it won't load.